# Argparse input and output directory

Tags: python, argparse

So I am trying to use python's argparse to get images from a directory modify them and store them in a new directory but I'm having trouble.

For example say I have a directory named classes which has 50 different classes each having 100 different images.

```
classes > {A(50), B(50), ...N(50)}
```

Then I should so something with these images and save them into a new different directory classes_2

```
classes2 > {A'(200), B'(200),...N'(200)}
```

I want to be able to specify something

```
python filename.py --input classes/A --dest classes_2/A'
```

How can I use argparse in order to do this. Also I'm using scipy imsave however I have to change the path in my code every single time.

Edited:

Ok thank you @nosklo, Now the problem that I'm having is this I'm using imgaug library for image augmentation and my code is this:

suppose I have all the imports needed, cv2, imgaug, argparse, os, sys, etc.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--input', help = 'input directory', required = True)
parser.add_argument('--dest', help = 'destination directory', required = True)
args = ap.parse_args()

for filename in files:
    images = []
    image = cv.imread(filename)
    image_rgb = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BRG2RGB)
    images.append(image_rgb)

    #imgaug built-in functions
    seq = iaa.Sequential([ ... ])

    num_augs_per_image = 10

    # save images in format 001_07 
    # where 001 is the second image in your original data set 
    # and 07 is the 8th version of the 2nd image
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        image_augs = seq.augment_images([image] * n_augs_per_image)
        for j, image_aug in enumerate(image_augs):
            result = os.path.join(args.dest, "%03d_%02d.jpg" % (i, j))
            with open(result, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(image_aug)
```

I've also tried for the last part:

```
for i, image in enumerate(images):
            image_augs = seq.augment_images([image] * n_augs_per_image)
                for j, image_aug in enumerate(image_augs):
                    misc.imsave(os.path.join("%03d_%02d.jpg" % (i, j)), image_aug)
```

However when I call the file python filename.py --input /path/classes/A --dest /path/classes/B I do not get any of images saved in the new directory.

Like for example if I had 5 images in directory A I was expecting to have 50 images in directory B since I have augmented each image 10 times and want to save all versions of my original images.

Comment: All `argparse` can do for you is interpret the input, and give you 2 values, `args.input` and `args.dest` (both string values).  You have to write your own code to use those values.

Comment: @hpaulj: `argparse` can do more than that.  Take a look at the documentation for [the `type` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) of the `add_argument()` method of [`ArgumentParser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argumentparser-objects).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, true,  A lot can be done with `type`.  But a function that works well as a `type`, can be used just as easily after parsing to convert string values.  And I think, for a beginner, that will be less confusing.  I prefer to focus on `argparse` as a parser.  But there are extensions and alternative parsers that try to integrate parsing and execution (e.g. `plac`)

Answer (score 0):

I will help with the argparse part, so you can focus on your "something" you must do to the images:

```
import os
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some images')
parser.add_argument('--input', help='the input directory', required=True)
parser.add_argument('--dest', help='the destination', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

for path, dirs, files in os.walk(args.input):
    for filename in files:
        fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)
        result, result_filename = do_something(fullname)
        result_fullname = os.path.join(args.dest, result_filename)
        with open(result_fullname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(result)
```

This assumes your function `do_something` will be able to return a `result` and a new `result_filename` that will be used to write the file in the `--dest` directory - if you want to use the same filename just use the `filename` variable instead.

Comment: Ok thank you @nosklo but I have problems saving my images using this.  I have added an "answer" explaining my code and what doesn't work. I hope you can check it out. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @JackConti I have seen your updated code, but I don't see where your `files` variable is coming from - do you have the `for path, dirs, files in os.walk(args.input):` part in your code? What about the `fullname = os.path.join(path, filename)` part?